# Locking for multi-threaded hot swapping

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, locking

In my multi-threaded graphics application, I have certain assets like images, models, sound files and so on. Some of them are loaded from files on the disk. When those files change, I want to automatically reload them and update the corresponding assets that may be used all over the application. A similar use case is LOD. When models get far away from the camera, I want to replace them with cheaper less detailed versions.

While the assets get replaced, other parts of the application run in different threads and may read to those assets. So I need some locking. How can I provide proper locking to replace the assets while making it as easy as possible for the other parts of the application to use them?

For example, I could provide an abstract base class for assets. This could contain a shared mutex. Then, there would be a loader class, that internally stores assets and returns references to them.

```
class Asset {
public:
    std::shared_mutex access_;
};

class Loader {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T &load(std::string filename);
private:
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>, void*> assets_;
};

template <typename T>
class AssetLoaderTraits;
```

However, there potentially are a lot of assets, so let's try fewer mutexes. For example, the loader could keep a list of locked assets. There would be only one mutex to access the list. Moreover, we wouldn't need the asset base class anymore.

```
class Loader {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T &load(std::string filename);
    void lock(std::string filename);
    bool try_lock(std::string filename, std::chronos::duration trying);
    void unlock(std::string filename);
private:
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>, void*> assets_;
    std::shared_mutex map_access_;
    std::map<std::string> locked_assets_;
};

template <typename T>
class AssetLoaderTraits;
```

However, I still feel that this isn't the best solution. If there are thousands of assets, they are often processed in bulk. So there is a loop over a vector of assets and the locking mechanism would be required in every iteration. For locking, I'd also need to remember the filenames of all assets I want to use. (Also, it feels weird that the loader holds the locks.)

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Image&>> images;
Image &image = loader.load<Image>("/path/to/image.png");
images.push_back(std::make_pair("/path/to/image.png", image));
// ...

for (auto &i : images) {
    std::string &filename = i.first;
    Image &image = i.second;
    loader.lock(filename);
    // ...
    loader.unlock(filename);        
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I'm over-complicating this and have overseen a much simpler solution. How is this situation commonly solved? My goals are to have a simple interface and good performance for iterations over large collections of assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mutexes is nearly guaranteeing that you will have stuttering in your use of assets. Consider that you start loading another version of an asset, then the display routine wants to use it, but it is locked and the thread therefore is blocked until it is unlocked.

You could instead use share_ptr, the consumer will keep a share_ptr on the asset until it is no longer used.

- remember to keep it around if you give a pointer to data in the object to a render function, else the render function might reference a NULL).
- remember to unreference the pointers after the render no longer uses it.

The loader just loads the new data and when finished loading does an atomic switch on the assets so the next request from a consumer gets the new asset.

- if 2 consumers gets 2 different versions of the same asset, is it then a huge problem? It should resolve after one update, unless its music or sounds or other with duration.

ps.
Some code review.

- When using mutex try using [lock_guard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock_guard/?kw=lock_guard) as RAII pattern.
- Often its better to avoid std::map (and std::list) and use std::unordered_map or std::vector instead due to performance.
- difficult to read type declarations

  std::map< std::pair< std::string, std::type_index>, void*>

if your using [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) you could write something like this

```
using AssetId = std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>;

std::map<AssertId, void*>
```

if that is what you really meant.

Comment: Do you basically suggest handing out double pointers to the consumers? The loader could then change the pointer's target which should be an atomic operation. Different versions for two consumers are fine. However, the sound example made me think because I'd like the playing sound to stop on reload and start the new one (maybe resume at the same position). For this I might be better off with callbacks. Thanks for the code review!

Comment: The std::shared_ptr is a reference counter and the assets should implement a destructor that takes care of cleanup.

Comment: Hm, which atomic operation would then allow swapping the assets pointed to by the shared pointers?

Comment: The consumers will have their own shared_ptr, you simply replace the value in your table with the new one, and then when the consumers next time ask for the value they get the new one.

Comment: I have struggles understanding this. How can the replace operation be atomic for larger objects? With double indirection I could have a chance since only a pointer address would need to change which could be atomic on modern CPUs (but I'll have to check).